# Can we glue goza mats on the floor?

Tags: flooring, floor

Is it possible to cover the whole floor of goza mats and glue the mats on the floor? It is to have the floor look like tatami.

I would like to know how to lay goza mats, having it stick to the floor. (Therefore not using the mats as yoga mats but as a full fledged flooring; not laying them loose either as if they were carpets)

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd use standard commercial carpeting adhesive.

Comment: Is this for a stage set?   If not, I have a hunch you won't be so thrilled a year down the road.

Comment: It is for a regular bedroom.